# how to generate all combinations of 2 lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to generate combinations of 2 lists which have 4 elements each.

For example, `list([1,2,3,4],[x,y,w,z],L).` should return

`L = [(1,x),(1,y),(1,w),(1,z),(2,x),(2,y)|...]` as the answer.

This is my code:

```
comb([],[],[]).
comb([H1|_],[H2|_],[H1|H2]).
comb([_|T1],[_|T2],L):- comb(T1,T2,L).
```

... and it prints:

```
L = [1|y] ;
L = [2|x] ;
L = [].
```

... which is not the correct answer. Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be expressed as:

> Find all pairs `(X, Y)` such that `X` is a member of `List1` and `Y1` is a member of `List2`.

This can be directly translated into Prolog:

```
list_pairs(List1, List2, Pairs) :-
    findall((X,Y), (member(X, List1), member(Y, List2)), Pairs).
```